# Is $((x_1,x_2), (y_1, y_2))$ will form inner product or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem taken from hoffman kunz books

[image]

My attempt  : if i take  $\bar y_1=x_1$   and $\bar y_2= x_2$

then  $((x_1,x_2), (y_1, y_2)) = x_1^2 + 2x_2x_1 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2$

Now im converting them into matrix $A,$ then $ A= \begin{bmatrix} \ 1& 2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$  that is $\det A < 0$

So  it contradicts , it is not define inner product  on $\mathbb{C}^2$

Is its  true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\det A\lt0$ does imply the function is not inner product, but you need some more argument.

The determinant being negative means one of its eigenvalues is negative because determinant equals the product of eigenvalues. Say $\lambda\lt0$ is one such negative eigenvalue of $A$, $x=(x_1,x_2)$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Then $x^TA\overline x=\lambda x^T\overline x$. The number $x^T\overline x$ is just standard inner product of $x$ with itself and is positive, so that $\lambda x^T\overline x$ is negative. The function defined is not positive-definite.

Comment: You can also use a particular example: with $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ you have $x^T A \overline{x}=-2$.